# PHP Dynamically generating redirects

Tags: php, apache-2.4, .htaccess, conf

I've recently moved all my of my rules from a .htacess file into a .conf file.  Now when I want to add a redirect rule to my website I have to edit the .conf file and `sudo apachectl graceful`.

I've now run into a problem in that I want to be able to dynamically generate my redirect rules from PHP.  Back before when I had my .htacess file running it would have been relatively easy - just include a file there that PHP has control over and all redirects would work perfectly.

Now, I could still use an include file but i'm not sure (or comfortable with) PHP running `apachectl graceful`.

What is the best solution here? As I understand it with my current set up apache definately needs to be restarted in order for the .conf file to take affect, is that correct?  If I returned to using .htaccess, could I just have one .htaccess in the root of the domain and restrict apache from using any other .htaccess files, so as not to slow down my server?

Comment: I would be trying to design things such that I can have 1, or a couple of generic redirects. Then have a part of my PHP application that handling processing the URL and deciding how to handle it rather than dynamically creating loads of redirect rules.

Answer (score 0):

> ...but i'm not sure (or comfortable with) PHP running apachectl graceful.

Well, exactly. You shouldn't even be thinking about trying to *edit* your server config from PHP. This shouldn't even be possible, or if it is then you are opening a huge can of worms in terms of security.

> ...when I had my .htacess file running it would have been relatively easy - just include a file there that PHP has control over and all redirects would work perfectly.

Do you mean by allowing PHP to edit your `.htaccess` file? This also has potential security risks.

However, `.htaccess` or even your main server config, is not necessarily the best place for *redirects* anyway (assuming you're talking about *external redirects*). These redirects are usually because a resource/page has moved and no longer exists. In this case it is often more efficient to process the redirect in your server-side code (ie. PHP) once you have determined that a 404 would otherwise be returned. The redirect is a low-priority task. Serving content to your site visitors is a higher-priority. You don't need the redirect-check to be performed on every request.